# Passing uninitialized 2D arrays as arguments in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

all. I've tried and tried to get my head around this, and feel I am almost there, but I'm getting so confused with how many '*' I need! I have a function that takes as input the string of a directory containing a data file, an int and pointers to two uninitialized 2D arrays. The function reads the data file and then allocates memory and fills the arrays accordingly.

This code is completely wrong, I know, but the idea is:

```
void main()
{
  double **Array1;
  int **Array2;
  int dimension1;
  char DirWork[100], buff[100];

  f_ReadData(DirWork, dimension1, &Array1, &Array2);

  sprintf(buff,"%lf",Array1[0][0]); // Causes segmentation fault
  printf(buff);
}
```

and

```
void f_ReadData(char *DirWork, int dimension1, double ***Array1ptr, int ***Array2ptr)
{
  int ct, ct2;
  double **Array1 = *Array1ptr;
  int **Array2 = *Array2ptr;
  char FullDirArray1[100], FullDirArray2[100];
  FILE *d_Array1, *d_Array2;

  sprintf(FullDirArray1,"%s%s,DirWork,"Array1.dat");
  sprintf(FullDirArray2,"%s%s,DirWork,"Array2.dat");

  d_Array1=fopen(FullDirArray1,"r");
  d_Array2=fopen(FullDirArray2,"r");
  fscanf(d_Array1,"%d", &dimension1);

  Array1 = dmatrix(0,dimension1-1,0,3); // allocates memory to Array1 (dimension1 x 3) elements, using nrutil
  Array2 = imatrix(0,dimension1-1,0,3); // allocates memory to Array2 (dimension1 x 3) elements, using nrutil

  for(ct=0; ct<dimension1; ct++) 
  {
    for(ct2=0; ct2<3; ct2++)
    {
      fscanf(d_Array1, "%lf", &Array1[ct][ct2];
      fscanf(d_Array2, "%d", &Array2[ct][ct2];
    }
  }
  fclose(d_Array1);
  fclose(d_Array2);
}
```

I've missed out error handling here, but I do have some of that in place... not that it's helping. I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to access the arrays from the main function.

If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it... I'm seeing *stars! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then number of stars is correct.

You are getting a segfault because you don't copy back the pointer to the buffers that you allocated. You initialize only f_ReadData:Array1 but you need to assign this value back to *Array1ptr.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to copy in the lines "Array1ptr = &Array1;" and "Array2ptr = &Array2;" to f_ReadData (they are in my real, lengthier code), but I still have a segmentation fault - maybe these lines contain the error??

Comment: Yes, it was these lines that contained the error. Someone on a different board kindly pointed out my stupidity. :-) Of course, it should have been `*Array1ptr = Array1;` etc. Thank you for your help!